# input transformer to get ec2 tags

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

How can I get cloudwatch to send me the project tag of the ec2?

I have a cloudwatch rule that notify me when an ec2 state changes (stop/start).
Right now the alerts is emailing the ec2 current state and instanceId.

```
{"ec2state": "running"}
{"ec2id": "i-someEc2Id"}
```

How can I get cloudwatch to also send me the project tag of the ec2?

```
{"instance":"$.detail.instance-id","state":"$.detail.state"}

{"ec2state": "running"}
{"ec2id": "i-someEc2Id"}
{"ec2project": "projectname"}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible.

Instead, you will need to write code that takes the Instance ID and then calls `DescribeInstance()` to obtain details about the instance, including tags.